# Test mode facebook page for custom tabs

Tags: facebook, iframe, facebook-tabs

I want to create a custom tab to a facebook page, so I can add an iframe and put a deployed web app inside it. But as the official docs say here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages/tabs/
I cannot add custom tabs if my page has less than 2000 likes. Is there any way to have a test page so I can check this feature without having the restriction of 2k likes?

Comment: Looking to this facebook bug https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/1978223865639904/ seems clear that there is not any workaround for the 2000 likes limitation